# Poor metallic reflections

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, reflection

I don't know whether this metallic reflection is correct. It seems that the glasses reflection on the table gets incorrectly broadened out to a fixed distance, rather than a smooth falloff. Here the table is a Principled BSDF with 1.0 Metallic and 0.1 Roughness. The Cycles render has de-noising turned off, and 2048 samples. Are there any parameters I can tune to improve this reflection?

[image: glasses frame]

Comment: Hello :). Principled BSDF shader in Cycles gives physically correct results. "Poor reflections" is kinda subjective. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is this EEVEE depth-of-focus? I've been trying to figure this one out myself...

Comment: cycles, and especially principled bsdf always shows a realistic result, so with the material as it is this should be correct, but if you especially want it to be a clear reflection (which is all I can come up with because I don't know what you want it to look like), just make the roughness 0

Comment: @JachymMichal That's what I suspected. I just wasn't sure if I should expect something cleaner at 2048 samples. Turning the roughness back down to 0 as EverythingLeafwing suggests is a fine solution.

Comment: @Jayson For final renders I rarely go below 5000 + denoiser. Cycles is a kinda slow engine :).